# Ember-cli required for latest version(s)?

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

Until recently I always used Gulp to compile/uglify/minify my Ember.js code and it worked great.
This was up to Ember 1.11

Now I wanted to upgrade to Ember 1.12 and noticed that Ember-cli is now the preferred and recommended way to install/upgrade Ember.js
Does this mean it's not recommended anymore to download the individual Ember libraries and compile everything myself via gulp?

My main concerns in using ember-cli are the following:

[1] It feels like I don't have enough control anymore over what's happening.
E.g. I need to have two html files in my frontend - 1 publicly accessible and 1 protected - and ember-cli seems to look explicitly for an index.html file.
I can work around it by placing the other html file in the "public" folder, but this feels more like a hack rather that a final solution.

[2] ember-cli is taking *a lot* of time to compile my application.
With Ember 1.11 and gulp it took only 2 or 3 seconds, while with ember-cli (using Ember 1.12) it's taking a lot more time for an even simpler application.
(Actually it currently only contains the login/registration part of the application whereas the app with Ember 1.11 and gulp also contained the application logic)

```
$ time ember build
version: 0.2.7
0.2.7

Could not find watchman, falling back to NodeWatcher for file system events.
Visit http://www.ember-cli.com/#watchman for more info.
Building..
services/websocket.js: line 39, col 31, 'SockJS' is not defined.
services/websocket.js: line 298, col 13, 'observerFunction' is defined but never used.

2 errors

services/util.js: line 6, col 9, Bad line breaking before '+'.
services/util.js: line 7, col 9, Bad line breaking before '+'.
services/util.js: line 8, col 9, Bad line breaking before '+'.
services/util.js: line 9, col 9, Bad line breaking before '+'.

4 errors

===== 2 JSHint Errors

Built project successfully. Stored in "dist/".

real    0m55.876s
user    0m35.935s
sys 0m2.643s
```

As you can see it takes almost 1 minute to build this very simple Ember code.

[3] With gulp I can update my live app on the fly using gulp-watch. With ember-cli something similar is available via "ember serve",
but this expects the application to run standalone, which is not the case with my app. I have to serve it from my backend app, which is written in java.

Answer (score 0):

Ember CLI is recommended, but it's **not required** for latest versions. You can still use "globals style", even for version 2.0-beta. So, if you are aware of what you are loosing you can still go with grunt, but I'd say you shouldn't expect support from official documentation/guides etc. Most addons are nowadays converted to Ember CLI, so it requires some effort to make it work with globals style app(there was `ember-cli-export-addon` repository on GitHub before, but now it's gone), however it's still possible to make Ember CLI addon work with globals.

Now, about your concerns:

1. It's possible that [Engines RFC](https://github.com/tomdale/rfcs/blob/master/active/0000-engines.md) will solve your problem.
2. 1 minute is long, maybe you've misconfigured something, or your app is indeed very big even with not many logic included, or you're running into Ember CLI performance problems on Windows, which can be solved.
3. Maybe you could bind filesystem changes, for example via `ln -s` from `dist/` to your backend app directory, or, for development purposes separate Ember app from your Java backend.

Comment: Thanks for the link to Engines, I wasn't aware of that and it sounds like a nice solution to my problem indeed.

Comment: (Can't edit previous comment, hence a new one)

1. Thanks for the link to Engines, I wasn't aware of that and it sounds like a nice solution to my problem indeed.

2. I am aware of performance issues on windows, but I'm running on linux  and my app isn't big at all. 
I really have no clue why it's taking so long

3. I am already separating my Ember app from my java backend by providing a webroot location in my java app.
However "ember serve" doesn't seem to "build" the app in the same way as "ember build" does. As a result the app isn't working correctly when "build" via "ember serve"

Comment: What I've wanted to say, and maybe didn't include this before - Ember CLI isn't the perfect answer for developer needs. For example, integration with VS is hard, performance of first build is sometimes very bad(and there's issue opened on GitHub), integrating developer experience with another apps/languages and I think we need to wait for Ember team to implement some features/solve bugs as Ember CLI is actively developed.

Comment: Apparently the less compilation is the most important cause of the slow build times:

`Build successful - 41927ms.

Slowest Trees                                 | Total               
----------------------------------------------+---------------------
LessCompiler                                  | 22685ms             
SourcemapConcat                               | 4172ms              
SourcemapConcat                               | 3940ms              
Concat: Test Support JS                       | 3068ms`

Comment: I can only agree with you. But seems like Less Compiler take 22s for you. Seems like very large styles or some issue. If that keeps you from upgrading, maybe try to start with dealing with less taking so long, or move to scss/sass? I'm writing about SCSS, because it's running fine for me. And I'm curious what differences are there between ember server and build that hit you?

Comment: The less compilation isn't taking that long when compiling via gulp, so it's something ember-cli specific.

I just tried again with ember server and now it works fine, so it was probably a caching issue with my browser (I'm now using Chrome while previously I was using Firefox)
Actually, the results in my previous comment are taken from ember server.

Comment: Yeah, but when using ember server first build is slow, but next builds(when you change something) are relatively fast, so it's not a problem if you could make your app to work with `ember s`.

Comment: Well, unfortunately even next builds aren't necessarily faster with ember server (actually they seem to be very random):
`Build successful - 41927ms
Build successful - 20189ms
Build successful - 27842ms
Build successful - 52970ms`

But overall it seems at least a bit better than continuously building everything from scratch via ember build.
Although 20 - 30 sec is still way too long...

Comment: I think you'd have to create issue in Ember CLI repository on Github, or provide your experience in already created issue, if you feel something's wrong(you could provide gulp as example of how things should feel, how many files you have).